# Como implementar un fichero conf usando Python

Tags: python

Necesito implementar un fichero de configuración de los utilizados en Linux/Unix, para poder acceder desde una aplicacion Python. Por ejemplo, dado el fichero file.txt que contiene:

```
# Hora inicio
hora_ini 14:00
# Hora final

hora_fin 22:00
```

Necesito que mi aplicación Python busque, por ejemplo, la etiqueta `hora_fin` y recupere la cadena `22:00` en una variable, no se si me explico bien.

Comment: Python tiene un módulo para leer los ficheros de configuración: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Carl0701. Por favor agrega cualquier información que muestre que has intentado hacer algo para resolver el problema, eso nos ayudaría mucho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar el módulo [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), pero antes tendrías que cambiar un poco tu archivo de configuración ya que `ConfigParser` trabaja con secciones.

Archivo de ejemplo `example.conf`:

```
[HORAS]
hora_ini = 14:00
hora_fin = 22:00
```

Con el archivo de ejemplo `example.conf`, tu script se podría ver así:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.conf')
hora_ini = config.get('HORAS', 'hora_ini')
hora_fin = config.get('HORAS', 'hora_fin')
print hora_ini
print hora_fin
```

El resultado sería:

```
14:00
22:00
```

No has especificado la versión de Python con la que estás trabajando, el ejemplo anterior funciona para Python 2.x, en Python 3.x el módulo se llama [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).

### Bonus

Si en algún momento intentas hacer algo parecido para, por ejemplo, una aplicación Web, lo que puedes usar es [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).

Con esta librería podrías pasar parámetros sensibles como la contraseña de tu base de datos a un archivo `.env` y no exponerlos en los scripts de configuración.

Simplemente creas un archivo de texto `.env` con los parámetros que deseas:

```
$ cat .env
SECRET_KEY="23a/&dl3u80=!)?jsl3"
DATABASE_PASSWORD="12345"
```

Ahora, las variables del archivo `.env` estarán disponibles como variables en el entorno del sistema. Por ejemplo, puedes pasar de esto:

```
SECRET_KEY = '23a/&dl3u80=!)?jsl3'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = '12345'
```

A esto:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
```

Mucho más seguro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @Carl0701 de nada, si te srivió no olvides marcarla como aceptada